nvidia a100 doesn't seen on lspci command in ubuntu with supermicro h12ssl-i motherboard
I have installed ubuntu 22 lts on my h12ssl-i motherboard and just after installation I can see my nvidia a100 on lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D" command. I installed cuda toolkit and nvidia-470 drivers. A100 still can be found on lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D" and even on nvidia-smi command. But I reboot my PC and A100 magically dissapeared from all commands. After reinstall ubuntu I still cant find A100 through lspci command
